# How to handle multiple group details in Jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this set of records:

colors table.

```
color_group | color_name | color_no
Primary     | Red        | 1
Primary     | Blue       | 3
Primary     | Yellow     | 2
Secondary   | Green      | 8
Secondary   | Violet     | 1
Secondary   | Orange     | 7
Others      | Pink       | 6
Others      | White      | 4
Others      | Black      | 5
```

I want to generate report like this.

```
Primary
  Red        1
  Blue       3  
  Yellow     2
Secondary
  Green      8
  Violet     1
  Orange     7
Others
  Pink       6
  White      5
  Black      4
```

how can i display it like this in jasper report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solved by using **group** on the `color_group` field and adding a `groupHeader` band to display its value.

**Example**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="group" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c1d9b4b7-6162-4b17-b871-3cf3b867d1ef">
    <field name="color_group" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="color_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="color_no" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <group name="colorGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{color_group}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="20">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e98d6fc1-1ecd-4af4-8250-d8aaa497011e"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{color_group}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="7ca1ac35-6249-4ba6-ac87-031f8d410d2e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{color_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="395b0cdd-4d2c-4d0b-93cd-7cad6daf3a4b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{color_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge this is the process to create and use group in iReport.

```
*Write desired query to fetch fields.
*Go to report name -> right click -> add report group -> 
 specify group name and group by object(in group-criteria) -> next ->
 add group-header and footer if needed(in details) -> finish.
*Use this group where ever necessary(by using 'print when group' expression 
 as created group).
```